# Python Regex Comparison - Comparing a list of paths against a set of regex expressions with variables

Tags: python, regex

MY GOAL
To compare i.e. re.matchall() a list of paths such as the ones below

```
C:\Users\dir1\file1
C:\Users\dir1\file2
C:\Users\dir1\file3
C:\Users\dir1\dir2\file1
C:\Users\dir1\dir2\file2
C:\Users\dir1\dir2\file3
C:\Users\dir1\dir3\file1
C:\Users\dir1\dir3\file2
C:\Users\dir1\dir3\file3
C:\Users\dir1\dir4\file1
C:\Users\dir1\dir4\file2
C:\Users\dir1\dir4\file3
```

against a regular expression such as the one given below

```
re.match('C:\\\dir.*?\\\item.*', entry.strip("\n")) != None:
```

where I want *dir* to be treated as a literal string and *item* is an element of a list. I'm iterating through. *entry* , which is an element of a list so the code looks like

```
CompList = ["dir1\file1",
"dir1\file2",
"dir1\file3",
"dir1\dir2\file1",
"dir1\dir2\file2",
"dir1\dir2\file3",
"dir1\dir3\file1",
"dir1\dir3\file2",
"dir1\dir3\file3",
"dir1\dir4\file1",
"dir1\dir4\file2",
"dir1\dir4\file3"]

fileList_1 = self.convert_textfile_to_list(filePathOnLocal+fileName)

        for entry in fileList_1:
            for item in CompList:
                if re.match('C:\\\Users.*?\\\item.*', entry.strip("\n")) != None:
                   log.info("MATCH 1!")
```

The value of entry will be paths under *C:\Users* though not all paths under C:\Users might match the list of paths given in CompList.
The regex comparison I'm using isn't matching any of the items. 
Can you please help me out ?

EDIT

Some **actual string** examples ->
C:\Users\dir1\file1
C:\Users\dir1\file2 
C:\Users\dir1\dir2\file3

The **actual regex** is  re.match('C:\\Users.*?\\item.*', entry.strip("\n"))
where
Users -> is a literal string.
item  -> is an element/variable.

EDIT 2

What's written in italics are the values I captured by means of a breakpoint

```
for entry in fileList_1: *entry: 'C:\\Users\\dir1\file1\n'*
    for item in UserSettings_List_DirOnly: *item: 'dir1\\file1'*
        if re.match(r"C:\\Users.*\\.*%s.*"%item , entry.strip("\n")) != None:
            log.info("MATCH 1!")
```

Comment: *"The regex comparison I'm using isn't matching any of the items. Can you please help me out?"* -- Can you please provide an example of an **actual regex** being used, and an **actual string** being matched against? It's much easier to answer questions that have provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: *"where item -> is an element/variable"* -- That's not a complete, verifiable example. If `item` is a variable, then what does your code look like? You've written it as a literal string. What does `item` actually equal? (Does it, for example, contain any special characters?)

Comment: for item in CompList: , so how do I write item as a variable inside re.match() ? I guess that's the gist of my question. An example of that inside re.match should help

Comment: See my answer for variable inside re.match() syntax

Comment: @TLOwater, it doesn't seem to be working. Please see EDIT2

Comment: Works 100% with mine "re.match(r"C:\\Users.?\\%s.*" % item, entry.strip('\n'))" but did you change the CompList values to have "\\"s in them? Because if not it won't work properly

Comment: yes I corrected my CompList values by replacing \ with \\

Comment: Ok I checked against my own code - I put an r in front of the CompList entries (and didn't mention it). That is the difference that makes it work.

Comment: Has it not worked Dhiwakar?

Comment: Thank you so much it did do the trick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to format the CompList to match the regex i.e. "`dir1\dir2\file1`" should be `r"dir1\\dir2\\file1"`. Your regex is also slightly off, it should be:

```
re.match(r"C:\\Users.*\\.*%s.*" % item, entry.strip("\n"))
```

The use of triple '\'will try to escape the U in Users and the style for inserting a variable that I could find was either as above or using .format rather than entering the variable directly (which I presume will evaluate the word item not the actual variable value).